# ‘node-gyp rebuild’ installation error when adding a package to meteor app in Windows 7

Tags: node.js, windows, meteor, npm, node-gyp

I was trying to add a package (mizzao:turkserver) to my Meteor application, but I kept getting this error:

```
mizzao:turkserver: updating npm dependencies -- request, libxmljs,
validator, querystring, async, deepmerge...  
gypnpm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601  
npm ERR! argv  
"C:\\Users\\PC4all\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.1.3\\mt-os
.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\\\node.exe"
"C:\\Users\\PC4all\\AppData\\Local\\.meteor\\packages\\meteor-tool\\1.1.3\\mt-os
.windows.x86_32\\dev_bundle\\bin\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"  
"install" "libxmljs@0.8.1"  
npm ERR! node v0.10.36  
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.3  
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE  

npm ERR! libxmljs@0.8.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`  
npm ERR! Exit status 7  
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! Failed at the libxmljs@0.8.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.  
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the libxmljs package,  
npm ERR! not with npm itself.  
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:  
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild  
npm ERR! You can get their info via:  
npm ERR!     npm owner ls libxmljs  
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.  

=> Babel active on file extensions: es6.js, es6, jsx    
=> Errors while adding packages:

While building package mizzao:turkserver:  
error: couldn't install npm package
```

I am developing my Meteor application on a Windows 7 machine and from what I have been able to gather from posts on forums, the error seems to be related to that fact (interaction between npm and Windows - I did not find any posts describing the same problem on Linux machines).

I've already tried installing the latest Python version and MS Visual Studio 2013 as suggested here: https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation, as well as setting some environment variables as suggested here: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/2754. But none of those helped.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As I described in [this comment](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4802#issuecomment-124569236), this seems to be an issue with the Python path being set incorrectly for npm, as Meteor's distribution of npm isn't hooking it up correctly. Most Linux distros come with Python, but Windows doesn't, so it is correlated with running Windows.

It can be fixed by making sure that Python is installed, then running the following command:

```
npm config set python C:\Python27\python.exe
```

The use of an old `libxmljs` is because `mizzao:turkserver` is dependent on a relatively old [node MTurk API](https://github.com/jefftimesten/mturk), which I'd like to wean it off of at some point, but isn't such a high priority at the moment.

See also:

- https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/163
- https://www.robertkehoe.com/2015/03/fix-node-gyp-rebuild-error-on-windows/

Comment: I have Python 2.7.6 installed, the PYTHONPATH environment variable is set to C:\Python27\python.exe, and I had already tried running

`npm config set python C:\Python27\python.exe`

but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: You have just helped me a lot.